# Brackets programme not launching Lubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, lubuntu

I have just started to use Linux, in particular,Lubuntu 16.04. I wanted to try to install a programme that would allow me to participate in Web Development, so I decided to install a programme that is called 'Brackets', as this looked liked the best option. Although when I installed the programme and clicked on it in order to open the programme, nothing happened , this was also the case I tried to launch Spotify. I got an error that said something along the lines of, 'Ubuntu has encountered an error', although I am not completely sure about this. I would like to know how to get these programmes to open as at the minute they are not doing so. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did -

Ubuntu has a PPA for Brackets installs which will automatically import libcrypt11 while also keeping Brackets up to date automatically.

To install from PPA, open a terminal and then:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/brackets
```

If asked to install key say “yes”

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install brackets
```

https://nathanjplummer.github.io/Brackets/